# 2 Servers - SharePoint 2013 (server1) and SQL Server 2014 (server2)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

We are performing a POC and we have two POC servers to setup SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2014 to test Azure AD with external access.

> The question is does the SQL Server (Server 2) require Internet access.

I know that the SharePoint 2013 machine will need Internet Access because there is know way to talk to Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server communicates with the Other SharePoint server, no internet access is needed, i suggest to check out this link [Using Azure AD to enable partner access to SharePoint 201x](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2017/04/07/using-azure-ad-to-enable-partner-access-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server does not require Internet access.